# drush update - php.ini problem

Tags: drush, updating

I am trying to update drupal using drush from Version 7.36 to 7.38 with >drush up drupal
the process finishes in 2-3 seconds stating update has successfully finished and a backup has been created.

As a result, drupal is still on 7.36 - no updates have been made.

but there is also an error stating  no php.ini found - and the created backup directory (where drush is looking for the php.ini) is empty:

```
(uiserver):xxxxx:~/kochlounge > drush up drupal
Update information last refreshed: Sa, 07/11/2015 - 16:07
 Name    Installed Version  Proposed version  Message
 Drupal  7.36               7.38              SECURITY UPDATE available

///some update-warnings snipped for readability

Do you really want to continue? (y/n): y

Source directory                      HERE COMES THE ERROR  [error]
/htdocs/drush-backups/db570947934/20150712144116/drupal/profiles/php.ini
is not readable or does not exist.

Project drupal was updated successfully. Installed version is now 7.38.
Backups were saved into the directory                                [ok]
/htdocs/drush-backups/db570947934/20150712144116/drupal.
Backups were restored successfully.
```

my drush status (snipped):

```
 PHP executable                  :  /usr/bin/php5.5-cli
 PHP configuration               :  /usr/lib/php5.5/php.ini /usr/bin/php5.5-cli
 PHP OS                          :  Linux
 Drush script                    :  /htdocs/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php
 Drush version                   :  7.0-dev
```

my .profile:

```
alias php="/usr/local/bin/php5.5"
alias php-cli="/usr/bin/php5.5-cli"
alias composer="php-cli ~/composer.phar"

export DRUSH_PHP="/usr/bin/php5.5-cli"
export DRUSH_INI="/usr/bin/php5.5-cli"
alias drush="~/.composer/vendor/bin/drush"
```

Has anyone got a clue as to why the update is not working, what may be wrong with the php.ini... ?
when trying to do updates for modules from drupal-backend, the site throws an error and goes in maintainance-mode.

Thank you!

Comment: Hard to tell what is wrong. The first thing to check is filesystem permissions. Make sure that the user that you are running Drush as has write access to everything inside the Drupal root, and everything in the backup location.

Comment: Permissions seem to be ok -

Answer (score 0):

Turned out that after a complete wipe and restore of my site the upgrade worked without that error.

Sorry, no idea what caused this in the first place!